# Make Image Text Appear And ReApear With Mouse How?

Tags: python, pygame

so what I am trying to do is make a text image appear when I click a sighn it should appear the exit and the image sprite and then when my mouse clicks the exit image it should delete both the image and the exit this is what I I tried but doesnt seem to work

> > what I have tried to do I doesnt seem to work

```
    for alrt in alerting:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for exi in exiting:
                    exi.draw()
                for te in texting:
                    te.draw()
                for one in range(len(exiting)-1,-1,-1):   
                    del exiting[one]
                for s in range(len(exiting)-1,-1,-1):
                    del exiting[s]
```

Comment: It the text should be visible permanently after the mouse click, then the text has to be drawn in the application loop. Note, the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs only once.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is to be permanently visible after the mouse click, the text must be drawn in the application loop. Note that the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs only once.

```py
sign_clicked = False 

run = True
while run:

    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if not sign_clicked:
                if # test if mouse is on sign
                    sign_clicked = True
            else:

                if # test if exit is clicked
                    # [...]

                if # test if the image is clicked
                    # [...]

    if sign_clicked:

        # draw exit and image
```

Comment: [script image](https://gyazo.com/68683c5b0b1a846b30a00897e833a132) am I doing something wrong it seems like when I click the alert sign nothing appears